# Can chat editing be made inline?

Tags: feature-request, edits, chat

I really like the recent change that allows inline editing for questions and answers - it makes editing much easier since you can see context like the original post or comments.

Could the same functionality be extended to chat? Currently editing takes place in the same textbox used for chatting. It would not have the same impact as the Q/A editing did, but I think it would make chat editing a bit more seamless.

Comment: Note that you can edit messages "inline" if you're viewing a chat transcript and you click "edit" from the dropdown next to the message.

Answer (score 4):

What's the benefit of that? The benefit of inline post editing was not needing to go to a separate page that has less information -- inline chat editing switches from typing in a text box at the bottom of the page to typing in a text box in the middle of the page

Comment: Like I said in the post, it would have nowhere near the impact as post editing. It's a usability upgrade, and I think that even small ones are worth doing if time is availabe.

Answer (score 4):

I would like this, personally.  The chat post looks really similar to the chat edit/entry box when it's being edited, and it looks editable -- but it's not.  Same background color and font style:

[image]

After months of using chat I am still unused to this, which is not normal for me.  The usability could definitely be improved.

Even a small change like changing the styling of the chat being edited to look less like the chat edit/entry box would be good.

Ideally though, I could just click edit on a post and edit it directly, without needing to go down to the editing box.